# How to deal with DATE-type in MYSQL & PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, simpledateformat, date-formatting

I'm building a website with php and i'm using the DATE-type in my MYSQL table to store dates. The problem that i have is that this stores the dates by default in the format YYYY-MM-DD. But i need this format DD-MM-YYYY to appear on my PHP page with the possibility of calculating the amount of days between 2 different dates. How can this be achieved?

Comment: Where do you want to make the calculations? In the php or in the query?

Comment: I want to make those calculations in php, when the page is requested.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to convert a string representation of the date to an actual date object in php, then use the [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function to spit out the date as any string format you wish.  Also, you can be `strtotime` to perform date calculations.  Additional information can be found at [this blog post](http://www.fayazmiraz.com/php-mysql-tutorial-how-to-use-mysql-date-correctly-in-php-date-function/).

```
$phpDate = strtotime($stringDateFromDb);
date('d-m-y', $dateFromDb);
strtotime('-3 days', strtotime($stringDateFromDb));
```

Comment: a date string from the db will not work. You'll just get Jan 1/1970 since the string will evaluate to time-value `0`.

Comment: @MarcB Then just use strtotime to convert the string to a date (as shown in edited answer)

Answer (score 0):

That's a display problem. Use mysql's [`date_format()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function to convert to whatever your display requirements are, e.g.

```
SELECT date_format(datefield, '%d-%m-%Y'), ...
```

Comment: When i query this in phpmyadmin it works fine. In php i dont get anything returned. ` $query2  = "SELECT date_format(startdate,'%d-%m-%Y'), date_format(enddate,'%d-%m-%Y') FROM articles WHERE pkArticle='$articleID'";  $result2 = mysql_query($query2)  while($datums = mysql_fetch_array($result2)){
    
$startdatum    = $datums['startdate'];
$einddatum     = $datums['einddate'];
   }`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for a way to do it:

```
$date_str = '2012-05-20'; //you get it from db
$date_now = strtotime($date_str);  //convert it to unix timestamp
$yesterday=$date_now-24*60*60;  //make calculations
echo 'yesterday was: '. date('d-m-Y',$yesterday);  //date() returns the date in format you need
```

Further example here: [How to calculate the difference between two dates using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php)

Comment: it's easier and more intuitive to use `strtotime` -- `$yesterday=strtotime('-1 day',$date_now);`

Comment: You are right, I just wanted to show how to use unix timestamp.